# Why can't I get access to an external class in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a breakout game in adobe flash. I defined a document class, BreakOut.as, and set it to .fla file. I wrote another class Player.as, but I failed to get access to Player.as in my BreakOut.as. Here is the code:

BreakOut.as:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
public class BreakOut extends MovieClip
{
    public function BreakOut()
    {
        var background:Background;
        background= new Background();
        addChild(background);

        var playerone:Player;
        playerone=new Player();
        playerone.x=50;
        playerone.y=50;
        addChild(playerone);
    }
}

}
```

Player.as:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Player extends MovieClip
{
    public function Player()
    {

        player.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        player.graphics.drawRect(0,0,20,100);

    }
}

}
```

Adobe flash keeps telling me: Access of undefined property Player. Well, Background.as is another class, and I can get access to it without any problems. But it just won't work on Player.as.

Comment: Hmm, everything seems fine (mind you, I haven't done AS3 in a few years). Is Player.as in the same directory as BreakOut.as? Oh -- one more thing: what is `player` inside Player.as? Is that the location Flash is reporting the error at?

Comment: @Cameron Exactly! The player inside Player.as caused the whole problem. loxxy gave me the right way. Also, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    player.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
    player.graphics.drawRect(0,0,20,100);
```

By this, if you are trying to initialize **Player** by drawing a rectangle, you should be rather using ***this***:

```
    this.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
    this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,20,100);
```

---

Do note that **Player.as** should also be in the same path as the fla's classpath.

Comment: Many thanks!!!Everything works fine now. These problems has been haunting me for a whole day, finally I can carry on with the rest parts of the game. Thank you again for your help.